# Split one SQL column into multiple based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to split one column in two based on some condition. Here is an example of table:

```
id | title
----------
1  | one
2  | two
3  | three
4  | four
```

So, I'd like to have a view with two columns like `id1` and `id2`, first one will contains ids that are lower than 3, second one - the rest ids, results should be consecutive. Expected result is

```
id1 | id2
----------
1   | 3
2   | 4
```

Comment: Is this real data/desire? Or this is just a way to simplify more complex  problem?

Comment: @gotqn yes, it's simplified description, but the goal is to split one column into two by condition, without any additional requirements/columns. I got two sets of data with same size and need to split them accordingly. Please let me know if I'm missing something important

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more data, the exact requirement is not entirely clear.  Here is one interpretation using `ROW_NUMBER()` with pivoting logic:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1 AS rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN FLOOR(rn / 2) = 0 THEN id END) AS id1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN FLOOR(rn / 2) = 1 THEN id END) AS id2
FROM cte
GROUP BY rn % 2
ORDER BY 1;
```

Here is a working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/MXSXXF6Q).

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to 1 and 3 in one column and 2 and 4 in the other in the example given by the OP?

Comment: @JensSchauder No, and you read my answer wrongly.  See the demo here: https://dbfiddle.uk/MXSXXF6Q

Comment: Ok, I get it now. I kind of missed the `MAX`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
select small.id as id1, big.id as id2
from(
  select id, title, 
    row_number() over (order by id) rn
  from demo
  where id < 3
) small
join (
  select id, title, 
    row_number() over (order by id) rn 
  from demo
  where id >=3
) big
on small.rn = big.rn
```

For simplicity I used a `JOIN`, if you can't guarantee both parts have the same number of rows, you might have to use a `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or [`FULL OUTER JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-can-i-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql)

I put a [working example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FWKIjuB4).

This approach compared to variants using `GROUP BY` is that all other columns can easily be used in the final query.

Comment: You need `row_number` rather than `rownumber`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Correct. Thanks for noting. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is compatible for mysql 5 :

```
select 
  MAX(case when id <= 2 then id END) AS id1,
  MAX(case when id > 2 then id END) AS id2
from (
  select 
  id,
  IF(id%2, 1, 0) as gp
  from TABLE1
) as s
GROUP BY gp
ORDER BY id1,id2
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally for a table of N rows

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 'one' AS title UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'two' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'three' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'four' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'five' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'six' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'seven'
),
cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) - 1 AS rn,
      count(*) over() cnt
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT 
    max(CASE WHEN rn < cnt / 2 THEN id END) AS id1,
    max(CASE WHEN rn >=cnt / 2 THEN id END) AS id2
FROM cte
GROUP BY rn % round(cnt/2) 
ORDER BY 1;
```

Returns

```
id1 id2
1   5
2   6
3   7
4   null
```